# main.ERROR: The "EM0EM00284-100" product couldn't be removed

Tags: magento2, product, delete, magento2.3.5

After upgrade to Magento 2.3.5, When trying to delete products from the catalog, we receive an error. This occurs on various types of products, from virtual products, simple products, configurable products, with no relation to other products or even any data in the product itself. This is on a relatively new installation of 2.3.5.

Here's the error message we get on the front end:

`main.ERROR: The "EM0EM00284-100" product couldn't be removed. [] []`

Comment: Please check the exception.log file for this. Is there any error?

Comment: @MoinMalek Thanks for the comment.
We have checked in exception.log and found that issue because of Amasty_pgrid_qty_sold extension.

Comment: Excellent Suresh

Answer (score 0):

**issue was:**
cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`amasty_pgrid_qty_sold`, constraint `amasty_pgrid_qty_sold_ibfk_4` foreign key (`product_id`) references `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) on delete no action on up)

**comment:**
we need to remove entry from amasty_pgrid_qty_sold before actual product delete from catalog_product_entity table.

we have created a module to implement catalog_product_delete_before observer
to remove the product from the amasty_pgrid_qty_sold table.

and it's worked.